# problem with uploading .bin file to esp8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have a board which has esp8266-07 on it and it has the pins to upload .bin file. I know this chip is alive. I had an pl2303 like this:

[image]

which worked all fine and I could upload my .bin file to the chip.
now I have a hw-597 like this (without the jumper):

[image]

I have tested the hw-597 and it is OK.(I put a jumper between RX and TX and then I could send and receive data.)
but when I'm using "nodemcu-pyflasher", it can not connect to the esp8266 (like the image below):
[image]

what should I do for it?

Comment: Jumper's purpose is to configure proper levels (3.3v or 5v ) for RX and TX pins. If you use external power for device then set jumper between 3.3v and VCC to be on the safe side. But someone mentioned that when do you not use jumper at all then VCC pin has 3.3v on it. So you could probably use 3.3v pin to power your device and forget about jumper. https://www.reddit.com/r/esp8266/comments/96f323/flashing_the_esp8266_with_a_ch340/ee0vwn8/ .

Comment: I have exact same hardware HW-597 : I see 3.8V between RX and GND 
when jumper is between 3.3V and VCC. looks unsafe, it should be 3.3V between Rx and GND

However, my CP2102 shows proper 3.3 or 3.2V on RX when connected to mac pro usb

If i measure voltage between its 3.3V pin and GND, tht also shows 3.8V

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. the ch340 "can not" provide enough current to power up the esp8266, so it "can not" upload any code into it. but I on't have any problem such as that with pl2303. I bought a new pl2303 and it worked all fine for me.